# Linear gradient is not working when used with "background-attachment: fixed"

Tags: css, linear-gradients, background-attachment

I am trying to make a linear-gradient with percentage breakpoints while using "background-attachment: fixed". It is not working as I expected.

I've made a very simple fiddle about my question.

https://jsfiddle.net/f8v1h0ac/

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        Header
    </header>
    <main>
        Main
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0px, white 300px); */

  /* The code above is working but the code below is not. Note that the color at the bottom line of header is supposed to be white. */

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%);
}

main {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

PS: I guess this happens because the gradient's height is respective to the window height. But I don't have a clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the difference between what you are expecting and what is actually happening.

Comment: Uncomment the background-image css line above, and comment the background-image css line below to see the difference.

Comment: The problem is `background-attachment: fixed` makes the background size relative to the whole viewport. That's why it works when you use pixels and not percent.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the problem, too. I still need a solution, though.

Comment: Obviously :o) Unfortunately I think your best solution, given the HTML and CSS provided, is to either set the gradient using pixels or remove the whole `background-attachment: fixed`.

Comment: I have to have these. So I think I will do something that I hate:
Check the header height using JS and write dynamically in pixels.

Comment: My device height is 1440px and there is a huge difference. It's dark gray instead of white.

Comment: By the way, what's the reason you need `background-attachment: fixed`?

Comment: Design concerns. It would take too much time to tell since I cannot demo my original work here.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? I put the header content inside a div.

```
header { 
  height: 300px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/xkgkam74/